# Is the GOG snap installer on ubuntu software authenticity verified?

Tags: snap

[image]

I want to believe that this snap is not from a malicious package

Comment: The Github README file answers your question. Do you have reason to believe that the Snap contains malicious code?

Comment: I think we have to have a minimum of mistrust.
Even to suspect who this Daniel Liewelllyn is well-meaning.

Verification of authenticity does not exist without purpose
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/558017000367063061/573136345988333609/Captura_de_ecra_de_2019-05-01_14-18-40.png

Comment: In that case the answer is "No: Snaps are not audited by the Snap Store."